# Dummying an Electron session for Mocha/Chai tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, mocha.js, electron

I've built a single-page app off of chentsulin's [electron/react boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate), which comes with the following node script for testing:

`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 mocha --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --require ./test/setup.js test/**/*.spec.js"`

The boilerplate comes with a number of generic tests that are runnable at the outset (I confirmed this myself). It also comes with a number of webpack configs to suit different environments.

The app is fairly far along now, and is using [electron-json-storage](https://github.com/jviotti/electron-json-storage) to handle local storage. I just went back to writing tests, and when I run the `test` node script (with or without --renderer) I get the following:

```
[dirpath]/node_modules/electron-json-storage/lib/utils.js:30
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app;
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined
```

I've tried using webpack.IgnorePlugin to ignore electron-json-storage, but that doesn't do anything. My guess is that electron-json-storage is trying to refer to an instantiated electron session that doesn't exist. What's the easiest way of dummying this up?

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into the question, you should answer your own question below, and mark it accepted when you can.

Comment: Oh, great—thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using mocha (which came as part of the Electron-React boilerplate). Installing electron-mocha and changing the `test` script in the package.json resolved this problem immediately.

Comment: What did you change about the test script?